# Android : Sending Current location through whatsapp

Tags: android

Hello I am new to Android. In My Android Application i want to send Current location using whatsapp.  I used following code and send the message but i want to send the current location Coordinates. Thanks

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: So... what is stopping you from doing that? Obtaining location data is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and in many books on Android app development.

Comment: There is already the possibility to send your current location thru WhatsApp. Why do you want to copy something, that already exists